# Menu disappears on chrome until you mess with it in developer tools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, menu

I haven't touched anything, so I think it may have been a chrome update that happened recently.  But my menu, which is `div` with nested `ul`'s, randomly loads invisible.

If you open developer tools (`F12`) and mess with any of the css, it automatically reappears. I can add a style that is completely invalid css, just make stuff up, and the menu will re-appear.

Can anyone help me find what is causing [this](http://www.halotracker.com/Default.aspx)?
I'm on Chrome 33.0.1750.146 m

Comment: Off topic: Putting each of your top-level menu items in its own `ul` is odd. If a list has only one item, it probably shouldn't be a list, partly for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Also, please use http://validator.w3.org/check and validate the source code...there are so many errors

Comment: This `<div class="SiteBody" data-page-name="">` element is unclosed. There is also a `closed form` tag but no `open form` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input guys.  I understand some of my html is bad, and I will take your advice to clean it up.  However like I said, everything worked fine until recently w/ no code changes.

I decided to rip out the entire menu and replace it w/ modern html/css and in doing so, I discovered the problem.  I was using font 'FuturaMedium' as my menu font, and the latest update to Chrome 33.0.1750.146 introduced some bugs with fonts.  So even my brand new css menu wouldn't work with that font.

For now I pulled the font and I will figure out what I need to do to fix it.  Again, thanks.

[Link to bug](http://blog.typekit.com/2014/02/28/new-bug-in-chrome-v33-affecting-web-fonts/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your menu CSS or JS is improperly setting the heights of all the parent `ul` elements to `height: 0`. Upon hover, they expand.

Take my comment above to heart and restructure your menu with a single top-level `ul`, and make sure you're only hiding `ul ul` on load.

You might also try setting z-index on those top-level `ul` elements instead of their children:

```
#navbar ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your cuplrit. In css **mc_grid3.css**:

There is :

```
 .container:after, .header:after, .header-bottom:after, .navbar:after, .main:after, .content:after, .content div:after, .subcontent:after, .subcontent div:after, .footer:after        {
   content: ".";
   display: block;
   height: 0;   // Remove this
   clear: both;
   visibility: hidden; // Remove this too
}
```

Or remove `.header-bottom:after`  from the above css rule.

Comment: That's not it. I removed it and no change. Again this only happens in this version of chrome, all other versions work fine

Comment: did you remove `.header-bottom:after` ? or just height ? because you also have `visibility:hidden`